# Paired variables in the definition of function

Tags: c++, syntax

I am new to c++ and trying to translate a c++ program into python. I am confused about the syntax of the following code:

```cpp
void function(unsigned(*f)(unsigned st, unsigned hqid) ) const{
    if( f(st,hiddenControlBitId) ){
    // code here
    }
}
```

Can anyone points out what is meant by passing `unsigned(*f)(unsigned st, unsigned hqid)` as argument?

BTW, I am sure it is not the same as passing a pair `std::pair<int,int> f` as argument, because trying to invoke the function using a pair gives a compilation error `No matching function for call`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
unsigned(*f)(unsigned st, unsigned hqid)
```

Here `f` is a pointer to a function that thakes 2 parameters, both of unsigned type and returns un unsigned integer. The `st` and `hqid` can be completely omitted.

Example usage:

If you have such a function, for instance:

```
unsigned foo(unsigned a, unsigned b)
{
   return a + b;
}
```

then you can call `function` like this (I assume it's a method because of the `const` there):

```
obj.function(foo);
```

Answer (score 1):

`function` is a `const` method of a class (`const` can't be applied to non-class functions) that takes a single parameter `f` as input.

`f` is a pointer to a non-class function that takes 2 `unsigned` parameters as input and returns an `unsigned`.

For example:

```
unsigned addThem(unsigned st, unsigned hqid)
{
    return st + hqid;
}

someObj.function(&addThem);
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> void function(unsigned(*f)(unsigned st, unsigned hqid) ) const{
>      if( f(st,hiddenControlBitId) ){
>      // code here
>     }
> }
> ```

In this, `function()` is a member function of some class that accepts a single argument, which is a pointer to a function (named `f`) that accepts two arguments of type `unsigned`, and also returns an `unsigned`.

If `foo()` is a function defined as;

```
unsigned foo(unsigned x, unsigned y)
{
      return x + y;    //   some arbitrary operation on the arguments
}
```

and if `s` is an instance of the class that has `function()` as a member function, then a statement like;

```
s.function(foo);
```

would call the function `foo()`.    The `const` in the specification of `function()` would mean that the object `s` is not logically changed.

Answer (score 0):

It means a function of two (unsigned) integers that returns another.  There are [tools](https://cdecl.org/) to explain C’s infamous syntax for things like that.

Comment: I am sure it is not that case as I have tried to call the function with a pair, which only throws me a compilation error. But many thanks for that website!

Comment: @taper his answer might not have the best wording, but he is right.

Comment: @taper it is two distinct parameters passed individually, not as a single `pair`